# FlutterFire CLIを使えるようにしたいです

Tags: firebase, flutter

FlutterFire CLIを使えるようにしたいです。

前提
Firebase CLIはインストール済みでGoogleのログインも終わっています。

発生している問題・エラーメッセージ
[image: dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli を実行するとエラーが出てしまう]
↑上記のように「dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli」
を実行するとエラーが出てしまいます。

直前には
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]’メールアドレス’
が表示されているので、ログインまでは出来ているのですがPATHが見つからないというエラーが出てしまい進みません。
どうすれば解決が出来るのか教えて頂きたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: メッセージの通り `git` がインストールされていない様子。ないしはインストール自体はされているけど `PATH` が通っていないのかも。